# Python Looping through a list and assigning values

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list and want to change its elements

```
list = ['apple','potato']
```

Now, while this works

```
for i in range(list):
    list[i] = list[i].capitalize()
```

this one doesn't and I just don't get why

```
for i in list:
    i = i.capitalize()
```

I'm new to Python, my only background is C++ so I'm still trying to adapt to Python's style. If this kind of question had already been asked, please, feel free to redirect me and close this topic. Thank you!

Comment: Because doing so doesn't update the list. Only the variable i is changed.

Comment: As you iterate through the `for` loop, the variable `i` takes the _value_ of each element in the list. It is not a _reference_ to each point in the list. It is a separate variable. If you reassign it, you are only affecting the variable `i`.

Comment: So it's kind of a right value?

Comment: do `lst = [x.capitalize() for x in lst]` (avoid `list` as it is the list type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning in the loop will create a new name `i` inside the `for` that loses its value after each iteration.

That isn't really the point here though. You *can* have the effect get noticed if you were dealing with *mutable* substructures that can be altered in-place, i.e:

```
l = [[1], [2]]    
for i in l:
    i.append(2)
```

changes will get reflected accordingly (sub-list will be get `2` appended to them).

in your case, though, you have `str`s which are immutable objects. `i.capitalize()`, acting on a `str` instance will create a new copy of the value which is assigned and then lost. It will not affect the objects inside the list.

The value `i` in `for i in container:` *does refer* to the objects contained in the sequence. When you assign `i` to the result of `i.capitalize()`, the name `i` will now refer to the new capitalized instance returned.

Don't try and draw parallels between `C++` and `Python`, I know it sometimes makes learning easier but, other times, in can confuse the hell out of you.

<sub>Mandatory note: don't use `list` as a name, it masks the built-in name `list`.</sub>

Comment: This might help: http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables